# Why does pip claim to be installing a different version than I requested?

Tags: python, pip

I'm on Linux Mint with both Python 2 and 3 installed. I'm trying to install a particular version of pyparsing for Python3.

When I run an install command pip says it collects the version I requested using a cached file but then says it installs a different version. When I've done this in the past it would first uninstall another version, which it usually does (I've been alternating back and forth occasionally.) Then when I check which version is being imported in both Python2 and Python3, neither one matches the installation message. What could cause this? Thank you!

```
matt $ python3 -m pip install pyparsing==2.2.0 --force-reinstall
Collecting pyparsing==2.2.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/8a/718fd7d3458f9fab8e67186b00abdd345b639976bc7fb3ae722e1b026a50/pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pyparsing
Successfully installed pyparsing-2.4.0

matt $ python3 -m pip install pyparsing==2.2.0
Collecting pyparsing==2.2.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/8a/718fd7d3458f9fab8e67186b00abdd345b639976bc7fb3ae722e1b026a50/pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pyparsing
Successfully installed pyparsing-2.4.0

matt $ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyparsing
>>> pyparsing.__version__
'2.2.0'
>>> exit()

matt $ python
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:39:04) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyparsing
>>> pyparsing.__version__
'2.3.0'
>>> quit()
```

Comment: Maybe something is screwy with your cache? See if installing with `--no-cache-dir` changes anything. (If it does, you might want to clear your cache.)